# "subscription" in an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Let's say that I have this services

```js
    export class CacheApiService {
    ...   
      updateTokenCache() {
        const url = `${this.consultationBaseURL}/cache/idm/updateTokenCache`;
        return this.httpClient.put<any>(url, {});
      }
    }
```

AND

```js
export class CacheService {

    updateTokenCache() {
      return this.cacheApiService.updateTokenCache().pipe(
        catchError(err => throwError(err)),
        tap( res => {
          this.logger.info(`CacheService - updateTokenCache()`, res);
        })
      );
    }
}
```

whatever, this is not important

the issue is there:
In an other service i have this method that returns a token

```js
refreshToken(): Observable<string> {

    this.logger.debug('refreshToken()');

    return this.impersonateUser().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroySubject$),
      tap( token => {
        this.logger.info('token', token);
        if (token) {
          this.refreshTokenState(token);
          this.storeUserPrincipal(token);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

I want, once i get the token, set it in cache by calling the method updateTokenCache() from the CacheService, inside that Observable. But i want to return the first value (the token)

Do i subscribe to inside the tap() ? i guess not
this.cacheService.updateTokenCache().subscribe()

So i Cannot find a way to achieve this, and of course i want to do that inside that observable

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `switchMap` to cache the token and use `map` to return back the token instead of the response from the `updateTokenCache()` observable.

```js
refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
  this.logger.debug('refreshToken()');

  return this.impersonateUser().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroySubject$),
    tap(token => {
      this.logger.info('token', token);
      if (token) {
        this.refreshTokenState(token);
        this.storeUserPrincipal(token);
      }
    }),
    switchMap((token: any) => 
      this.cacheService.updateTokenCache(token).pipe(
        map(() => token)    // <-- send back the token here
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You Michael. I thought about that , the thing is I dont want to wait that updateTokenCache is completed to send back the token. But to be honest i dont know if it will behave like that. So i have just thought to have a Subject in the tap() to trigger the updateTokenCache .

Comment: @Yvan: Yes in the solution provided the flow will wait for the `updateTokenCache()` to complete. Then it's better to wrap it in a `Subject` like you said and trigger it as a side-effect.